# Overlapping instances and ORing constraints

Tags: haskell, types

I want to have a class which represents a property `P x` and I have an implication of the form `A x \or B x => P x`.

I have tried to implement this as follows:

```
class P x 
instance A x => P x
instance B x => P x
```

However this fails with overlapping instances if both `A x` and `B x` hold.

(I encountered this when dealing with natural numbers, Max and Min functions)

What is the correct way of expressing this constraint?

Comment: You cannot do this. The closest solution is to make one instance of `P` for each type to decide whether it should use `A` or `B`.

Comment: Having OR constraints would require the type checker to check if `A x` can be satisfied, and otherwise backtrack and check `B x` instead. This can easily lead to an exponential blowup, in the general case with many typeclasses. I think the Haskell designers avoided OR constraints intentionally to keep the complexity sane.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I encountered this when dealing with natural numbers, Max and Min functions"? Perhaps this is an XY problem.

Comment: @chi That makes quite a bit of sense, I had assumed that the constraint checked ended up something like prolog. I fixed it in the case of the Max and Min, by ensuring each case doesn't overlap, I was just wondering if there was a better solution to the more general problem.

Comment: It is indeed similar to Prolog, but there are some key differences. One is ensured termination (unless extensions are used to relax it), another is no-nondeterminism (no backtracking). Further, in Haskell the order of the clauses does not matter. Some extensions can affect some of these features (overlapping instances cause a form of non determinism / gives a kind of priority to clauses, roughly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Li-yaoXia is correct to say you can't do this. @Chi's explanation isn't what's going on. The `=>` in an instance decl is not implication (at least not in the Prolog sense).

```
instance A x => P x
```

Means `x` is an instance of class `P`. Typically the `x` will be a concrete type like `Int`, or at least a type constructor with argument variables like `Maybe a`. The `=>` then says: for type `x` an instance of `P`, require `A x`. That is, the implication goes the opposite way to how it looks.

It's a (common) newbie mistake to think it means 'first check all constraints hold then check if the instance head holds.'

Then also having

```
instance B x => P x
```

means `x` is an instance of `P`; also require `B x`. So if your two instances were to compile, you'd be requiring `(P x) IMPLIES ((A x) AND (B x))`. That is, the same as

```
instance (A x, B x) => P x
```

But your instances don't compile. Because their two heads are identical `P x`; that's a repeat. (I expect not an overlapping instances error, but a repeated instance error.)

Overlapping instances are nothing to do with what's going on here. (But @Chi is wrong to suggest they require any sort of indeterminism: if you try to write indeterministic overlapping instances, usually the program gets rejected. Unless you switch on all sorts of dangerous extensions.)